# Lit Element - a dispatched event in the child is not be received in the parent

Tags: lit-element

I am using Lit and I am dispatching an event from child to parent, but the parent does not see the event.

In the parent I have

```
connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback()
    this.addEventListener('info-updated', this._updateInfo);
}

_updateInfo(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

In the child I have:

```
_updateInfo () {
    const infoUpdated = new CustomEvent('info-updated', {
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true,
        detail: { ...  some info }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(infoUpdated);
    console.log('Dispatched');
}
```

_updateInfo is triggered by clicking a button in the child. The dispatch is made, but not received in the parent.

What am I doing wrong?

I have also tried:

```
this.addEventListener('info-updated', this._updateInfo.bind(this));
```

Comment: Have you tried, on the child selector in the parent HTML/markup, adding `@info-updated="${this._updateInfo}"`?

Comment: Change how you're adding the Event Listener:
`this.addEventListener('info-updated', evt => this._updateInfo(evt));`